# Finding longest matching subsequence in a certain column of database table

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I want to write a UDF that takes a string as parameter from User. Then the function has to find longest possible matching sequences/sub sequences in that column of table.

For example, 
Table-name --> Patient
Column name--> FirstName

Now, if user passed a string let's say `Johni` to this function and `FirstName` column has 'Johna' , `JohnDoe`, `Johi,`Simran`

The function shall return a table with value in decreasing order of match i.e

1. Johna
2. JohnDoe
3. Johi

and `Simran` should not be returned. I am kind of clueless about making this search in column values.

Comment: So you want to compare every possible substring from 0-n to all the strings in a column of the database?  This requires a procedure or library function, if you did it in SQL you'd have to limit the number of characters you'd accept and it would be inefficient.

Comment: @DeniseSkidmore: We can always calculate the percent match according to matched and unmatched characters once we have the values from column. Let's say, we are yet to write the function that calculates the percent match value, primarily i want a function to get all the values from the column that do match partially, and by partially, I mean the string passed should be present in those values, if no complete match for the string John is found in column values, then it should find string match for Joh and if yet nether, then for Jo and finally for J only.

Comment: @DeniseSkidmore: Limiting the number of characters is just fine.  Because let's just say I am not expectign any string with more than 20 characters in it. Should be fine then

Comment: If you can produce a column with the numeric value of the match, then finding values greater than 0 and ordering them is simple.

Comment: @DeniseSkidmore: Yes, but first we need to find values in column that matches the longest substring of the passed user string. How do we do that is what I need to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Difference` Function

```
SELECT a,Difference('Johni', a)
FROM   (SELECT 'Johna' a
        UNION
        SELECT 'JohnDoe'
        UNION
        SELECT 'Johi'
        union 
        select 'Simran') o
        where Difference('Johni', a)>=3
ORDER  BY Difference('Johni', a) DESC
```

**Update:**  To select from your table

```
SELECT FirstName
FROM   yourtable
WHERE  Difference('Johni', FirstName) >= 3
ORDER  BY Difference('Johni', FirstName) DESC
```

Comment: I can not do it this way, Johna, JohnDoe and Johi are just for example sake. There will be thousands of entries in database column where I have to pick strings with longest matching substrings

Comment: @Simran - Why?? Just to show a demo I have hard coded those values.  Updated check now

Comment: Let's say I have SImran, SimranKaur , John ,and SimranKaurKhurana as values in FirstName column. Now, If I pass 'simyy', it returns John first. Why is that?

Comment: considering sim from simyy and is present in Simran,SimranKaur and SimranKaurKhurana, should not these come first? Where is John coming from?